# What is the meaning of **much** in sentence: Nothing much ever happened?

Tags: word-usage

How to understand the meaning of the word **much** in the sentence: ***Nothing **much** ever happened***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of "not much" and "nothing much" as shorter versions of "not very much", which is the same as as "not a lot", or "very little". Your example sentence probably has some important context, for example, *My childhood was boring. Nothing much ever happened.* That would mean someone's childhood contained few interesting and notable events (because this phrase is usually not meant to be taken literally: of course *something* was occurring at each moment, but not something the author or speaker thinks is worth describing).